# How to secure a riak bucket?

Tags: security, riak

I want to implement riak cluster with 5 nodes.
But I want to be sure that a team will never reach other teams buckets.
Is there a way to implement a security layer ( reverse proxy,etc..) which allows protobuf and http client requests as well regarding basic rules ?

Answer (score 1):

Kind of a cop out, but [wait for Riak 2.0](https://github.com/basho/riak_core/pull/386).  It should have the security settings you are looking for, built in.

If you need this now, you will likely need to write an application layer on top of Riak that does authorization based on buckets/users.  You *might* be able to do it like you thought of with reverse proxy for the http client requests, but pb would be harder.